# How to make a Label's font size be as big as it can and also be able to resize itself? JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, text, label

Recently converting Swing project to JavaFX. One of my features I need converted is my ghetto JLabel that auto resized itself. Here is a semi part of my ghetto Swing code.

```
package driver;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class AutoResizeJLabel {


    public static void createGUI(){
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container container = jFrame.getContentPane();
        JLabel jLabel = new JLabel("HELLO");
        jLabel.setName("Hello");
        jLabel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        jLabel.setOpaque(true);
        jLabel.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener(){

            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                new Thread(new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        Font font = jLabel.getFont();
                        int height = jLabel.getHeight();
                        int width = jLabel.getWidth();
                        int fontSize = font.getSize();
                        int size = determineFontSize(jLabel.getText(), jLabel.getFontMetrics(font), fontSize, width, height);
                        jLabel.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.BOLD, size));
                    }
                }, "Get new size").start();
            }

            @Override
            public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {}

        });
        container.add(jLabel);

        jFrame.setSize(500, 500);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Method : Calculates the Middle Point of Graphic with Text
     * @param s : Text
     * @param g : Graphics
     * @param width : Width of the Component
     * @param height : Height of the Component
     * @return Middle Point
     */
    public static Point determinePoint(String s, Graphics g, int width, int height){
        //Initialize variables
        int stringWidth = 0;
        int stringAccent = 0;
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        // get the FontMetrics for the current font
        FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();

        // find the center location to display
        stringWidth = fm.stringWidth(s);
        stringAccent = fm.getAscent();

        //get the position of the left most character in the baseline
        x = (width / 2) - (stringWidth / 2);
        y = ((height - fm.getHeight()) / 2) + stringAccent;
        Point p = new Point(x, y);
        return p;
    }

    /**
     * Method : Determine font size of Component
     * @param s : Text
     * @param fM : FontMetrics of Component
     * @param fontSize : Original Font size
     * @param width : Width of Component
     * @param height : Height of Component
     * @return new font size
     * Credit : coobird over at Stack Overflow
     */
    public static int determineFontSize(String s, FontMetrics fM, int fontSize, int width, int height){

        //String Variables needed
        String stringText = s;
        if(stringText == null){
            stringText = new String("");
        }

        int stringWidth = fM.stringWidth(stringText);
        //int stringHeight = fM.getHeight();

        // Find out how much the font can grow in width.
        double widthRatio = (double)width / (double)stringWidth;
        int newFontSize = (int)(fontSize * widthRatio);

        //Determine new Font Size
        int fontSizeToUse = Math.min(newFontSize, height);

        return fontSizeToUse;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                createGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I say semi because I actually drew out with the graphics object rather than using the setText because I found the setText screwed with the positioning of the text if that makes any sense.

Anyways, I was wondering/hoping there was a easier way to have the text autosize so to speak to fill the whole Label object in JavaFX. I'm new to JavaFX and can't really find the equivalent of FontMetrics.